# Why does not work logout route in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

When I try to logout from admin panel I get error:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
```

But in routing there is route `logout`:

```
POST | logout |  App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout | web
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you clicking on a link to log out?

Comment: Yes, this is a standart link in admin panel

Comment: If you're clicking a link, that's a GET request, and the route list above shows that logout is a POST route

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do the following steps:

1.- if you're working with a class created by you to the login, specify it in config/auth.php:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Administrator::class,
    ],
],
```

2.- your model must inherit from class *Authenticatable*:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class Administrator extends Authenticatable{
    #code...
}
```

3.- add the logout() function on your LoginController, import *Auth* and *Redirect* classes

```
public function logout(){
    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::to('admin');
}
```

3.- specify the route that you will use to logout via GET

```
Route::get('logout','LoginController@logout');
```

It is all, this should work.

**NOTE:** Check if you are authenticated by the function `Auth::check()`

**Additional information:** When you are working with POST requests, Laravel needs to verify that the request are not a malicious request, for this Laravel needs an ecrypted code, this is called **csrf_token**, if you don't send this, by default all your requests will be not allowed.

Answer (score 4):

If you have upgraded to Laravel 5.3, the get logout route was purposefully removed during the upgrade.

> POST To Logout
>
> The Auth::routes method now registers a POST route for /logout instead of a GET route. This prevents other web applications from logging your users out of your application. To upgrade, you should either convert your logout requests to use the POST verb or register your own GET route for the /logout URI

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade

You need to change the have all logout links to forms so it can POST to the route. From https://github.com/acacha/adminlte-laravel/issues/94, something like:

```
<a href="{{ url('/logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();"> Logout </a>

<form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">{{ csrf_field() }} </form>
```

[Source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7d116dc5a008e69c97f864af79ac46ab6a8d5895/src/Illuminate/Auth/Console/stubs/make/views/layouts/app.stub)

Answer (score 1):

is your LoginController in Auth folder or Controllers  folder..
Maybe You're giving a wrong path.. 
if the LoginController is in Controllers folder, the Path should be 
 **Route::get('logout', 'App\Http\Controllers\LoginController@logout');**

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
<a href="{{ url('/logout') }}" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">{{ trans('adminlte_lang::message.signout') }}</a>
```

with

```
<a href="{{ url('/logout') }}" class="btn btn-default btn-flat" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();"> {{ trans('adminlte_lang::message.signout') }} </a>

<form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">{{ csrf_field() }} </form>
```

in mainheader.blade.php and it will fix.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access a `POST` route with `GET`.

You could:
 - create an ajax request with `POST`
 - wrap the button in a `POST`-form
 - create an additional `GET`-route to `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout`

Comment: I tried: `Route::get('logout', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');` It gives mne the same result

Comment: You need to remove the `POST` logout route. try`['except' => 'logout']` in your auth route.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a `GET` request to a `POST` route. Create or modify the existing route to accept `GET` requests (a redirect via a link is a `GET` request (most of the time))

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can add this to routes file:

```
Route::get('/logout' , 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
```